# How to merge dataview value

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataview

I want to merge same dataview value to another dataview ..

My code is here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lbxempname.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (lbxempname.Items[i].Selected)
    {
        string id = lbxempname.Items[i].Text;
        string substr = id.Substring(0, 8);
        string Expression = "Employee_ID='" + substr + "' and Punchdate >=#" + txtstartdate.Text + "# and Punchdate <=#" + txtenddate.Text + "#";
        DataSet4TableAdapters.sp_getalltimesheetTableAdapter TA1 = new DataSet4TableAdapters.sp_getalltimesheetTableAdapter();
        DataSet4.sp_getalltimesheetDataTable DS1 = TA1.GetData();
        datavw = DS1.DefaultView;
        datavw.RowFilter = Expression;
    }
    newdatavw = new DataView ();
    newdatavw.Table.Merge(datavw.Table);
}
```

First looping, dataview have some records like this...

```
   EmployeeId   EmployeeName    Department  Date            Day     Intime      Outtime     Late_After  Early_Before    Remarks
   00626243         HariharanJ  SBS IT      01-04-2012  Wednesday   06:40:00    15:00:00    00:00        00:00          P
   00626243         HariharanJ  SBS IT      01-03-2012  Tuesday     00:00:00    14:40:00    00:00        00:05          P
   00626243         HariharanJ  SBS IT      01-05-2012  Thursday    07:00:00    14:35:00    00:20        00:10          P
```

and second also having some records with same header..
But i want to Export both records in a single Excel with header and a single brake for each record. Please i was trouble to create it.I can Export a single record to excel but i can't export all record...

Answer (score 0):

```
newdatavw.Table.Merge(datavw.Table);
```

change your Code above:

```
newdatavw.Table.Merge(datavw.ToTable());
```

`DataView.ToTable();` ==>Return a new DataTable with DataView